# How can we list all the authenticated users session management in wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am using the identity server of wso2 wso2is-5.3.0 as an idp in order to autenticate my app (test app).
now when we logged into our app, the login page on the identity server will show to enter the credentials
what we are looking to is if there is any way to list all authenticated users in our test app and try to managing them?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the analytics capabilities of the Identity Server to monitor the sessions, set alerts, terminate sessions etc. For more information, refer [analytics documentation for IS 5.3.0](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Analytics).

Comment: thank you lucifer , i tried to follow up the tutorial, however i faced an error that blocked me, i logged it here :[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46320759/an-error-is-generated-when-we-tried-to-add-wso2-das-identity-server-repository)